# Seeking open source Geocoding tool which can be used commercially?

Tags: geocoding, software-recommendations, open-source-gis

Is there any Geocoding tool which is open source and can be used in commercial application?

We tried [Google geocoding API's](http://code.google.com/apis/maps/documentation/geocoding/) but cannot continue with it because of some licensing limitation.

Now we are exploring [GisGraphy](http://www.gisgraphy.com/) but haven't finalized it.

Is any other better alternative available?

Currently we want to GeoCode US data only but in future we may extend it to other countries.

Answer (score 18, accepted):

> This question has been converted to Community Wiki and wiki locked
>   because it is an example of a question that seeks a list of answers
>   and appears to be popular enough to protect it from closure.  It
>   should be treated as a special case and should not be viewed as the
>   type of question that is encouraged on this, or any Stack Exchange
>   site, but if you wish to contribute more content to it then feel free
>   to do so by editing this answer.

---

the best suitable option is not geonames OR openstreetmap but both, Geonames is good for city data, and Openstreetmap for streets, if you use both you will get a good dataset for geocoding. that's the goal of [gisgraphy](http://www.gisgraphy.com), use the two datasets to get the best relevance.

Comment: It's worth to note that geonames provides many datasets (e.g bounding box) only with the  "premium" subscription($ 750per year)

Answer (score 10):

Yes - try out [MapQuest geocoding](http://developer.mapquest.com/web/products/dev-services/geocoding-ws) and the [MapQuest Open Nominatim service](http://developer.mapquest.com/web/products/open/nominatim). We've ([MapBox](http://mapbox.com/)) used them on a number of projects and they're great and the TOS are quite reasonable.

Comment: I just tried MapQuest geocoding (Open Data version), and it was only able to geocode less than 50% of the addresses I tried. The addresses are in CO.

Answer (score 8):

US (TIGER data) Geocoder

Geocoder::US 2.0 is a software package designed to geocode US street addresses. Although it is primarily intended for use with the US Census Bureau’s free TIGER/Line dataset, it uses an abstract US address data model that can be employed with other sources of US street address range data.

https://github.com/geocommons/geocoder

Licence 
 GNU LESSER GENERAL PUBLIC LICENSE
https://github.com/geocommons/geocoder/blob/master/LICENSE.txt

Rest of the World:

The GeoNames geographical database covers all countries and contains over eight million placenames that are available for download free of charge.

http://www.geonames.org/export/free-geocoding.html

Comment: Thanks for suggestions. It will be good if we get a tool which can be used with other countries data.

Answer (score 6):

Gisgraphy use geonames AND openstreetmap data(total 47 millions of entries). I think it is actually the best opensource geocoder because it includes a full stack for geocoding and importing data.

Comment: Thanks for suggestion. We want to GeoCode address string, which is the best suitable option out of geonames and openstreetmap?

Answer (score 1):

[Nokia's Here.com](http://developer.here.com/plans) offers free 2500 geocoding requests per day, that's a good geocoding tool where Navteq data overperforms other geodata sources.

i suggest combining all the geocoders to get the best result.

Answer (score 1):

For geocoding Texas A&M Geoservices is probably the cheapest route and it is pretty accurate. I got 2,500 credits for free when I signed up to test it out, and purchased from there. -Kelsi

Comment: Could you please edit your question to include a link?

Answer (score 1):

You can easily try JDONREFv4 with ElasticSearch but data is not included.

Comment: Welcome to GIS@SE, it is more appropriate to provide links and qualifications in you answer to the solution you suggested. Best Regards.

Comment: Welcome to GIS@SE, adding links and qualifications to the answer you provided make sit easier for other users. Best Regards

Answer (score 1):

http://www.tigergeocoder.com/ using TIGER 2013 data, ready to run your own server instance in Amazon EC2 cloud and geocode 1,000,000+ per day.